# Get months between two dates ignoring the days

Tags: date, jodatime

I want to count the months between two dates, and only compare with their months while ignoring the days, so `2012-01-31` and `2012-02-01` should have `1` month difference between them.

I do this with joda-time:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
PeriodType yearMonth = PeriodType.yearMonthDay().withDaysRemoved();
LocalDate dt1 = new LocalDate(2012, 1, 31);
LocalDate dt2 = new LocalDate(2012, 2, 1);
int months = new Period(dt1, dt2, yearMonth).getMonths();
System.out.println(months);
```

But I got printed output:

```
0
```

Although I used `.withDaysRemoved()`, but it's not working. Do I misuse it?

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## `LocalDate`

As in Joda-Time, a `LocalDate` represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without a time zone.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of ( 2012 , Month.JANUARY , 31 );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of ( 2012 , Month.MARCH , 1 );
```

Establish the place to hold our results.

```
long countMonths = 0;
```

## `YearMonth`

The [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents, well, a year and a month. This is the conduit to considering whole months, as you want, rather than number of days.

```
YearMonth ymStart = YearMonth.from ( start );
YearMonth ymStop = YearMonth.from ( stop );
```

This `YearMonth` class has methods for comparison such as `isAfter`, `isBefore`, and `equals`.

The [`ChronoUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) class can calculate elapsed months between a pair of [`Temporal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html) objects. The `YearMonth` class fortunately implements `Temporal` and works with `ChronoUnit`.

```
if ( ymStart.isAfter ( ymStop ) ) {
    // Handle error condition. Unexpected input values.
} else if ( ymStart.equals ( ymStop ) ) {
    countMonths = 0;
} else { // Else different months.
    countMonths = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between ( ymStart , ymStop );
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "start: " + start + " | stop: " + stop + " | countMonths: " + countMonths );
```

> start: 2012-01-31 | stop: 2012-03-01 | countMonths: 2

## Half-Open

The results above are based on the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This approach is commonly used with date-time work, including throughout the java.time classes.

So, for example, lunch period starts at the first moment of the noon hour and runs up to, but not including, the first moment of 1 PM.

Another example: A week would start on a Monday and run up to, but not including, the following Monday. Or in this case, a pair of year-months from January and going up to, *but not including*, March; they yield a span of 2 months.

I believe using the Half-Open approach throughout your code leads to more clarity and less bugs. But if you or your users demand otherwise, add one to the results above.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Answer (score 0):

The month arithmetic of `LocalDate` will and must always use the day-of-month for its calculations. The fact that you have specified the period type such that the days shall not be used only means: The final result shall not show any days (but the day-of-month-component of `LocalDate` is internally still used).

However, if you use another type, namely `YearMonth`, then this type defines a different month arithmetic:

```
LocalDate dt1 = new LocalDate(2012, 1, 31);
LocalDate dt2 = new LocalDate(2012, 2, 1);

YearMonth ym1 = new YearMonth(dt1.getYear(), dt1.getMonthOfYear());
YearMonth ym2 = new YearMonth(dt2.getYear(), dt2.getMonthOfYear());

PeriodType yearMonth = PeriodType.yearMonthDay();
System.out.println(new Period(ym1, ym2, yearMonth).getMonths()); // 1
System.out.println(new Period(ym1, ym2, yearMonth.withDaysRemoved()).getMonths()); // 1
```

Here you can also see that - in context of `YearMonth` - suppressing the days in `PeriodType` is not relevant.